# How to set data item in datasource for listview kendo ui

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My data listview grid structure is like this.

```
<div id="listView">
 <div class="product"><h3>India</h3></div>
 <div class="product1"><h3>Gujarat</h3></div>
 <div class="product"><h3>Surat</h3></div>
</div>
```

I want to set new data in which datasource has class product1.

ex. like

```
<div class="product1"><h3>Gujarat</h3></div>
```

I want to change Gujarat to other name.

I was use below code but this set only first element and not check particular class.

```
var firstItem = $('#listView').data().kendoListView.dataSource.data()[0];
firstItem.set('name','The updated Name');
```

So kindly reply solution if you know.

Comment: How do you initialize the tree view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might try:

```
var list = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
var uid = $(".product2", list.target).data("uid");
item = list.dataSource.getByUid(uid);
item.set("name", "The updated Name");
```

What I do is:

- Get a reference to your Kendo UI ListView
- Extract the `uid` for the list element.
- Use `getByUid` from `DataSource` to find the element with that `uid`.
- Updates `name`.

A second approach likely less efficient:

```
var list = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
var idx = $("div", list.target).index($(".product1", list.target));
var item = list.dataSource.data()[idx];
item.set("name", "The updated Name");
```

- Get a reference to your list view.
- Then find the index by retrieving all `div` inside the list (each item in the list) and then finding the index of the one having the class `product1`.
- Get item from the ListView data source.
- Finally, updates the `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like this?

```
var firstItem = $('#listView.product1 h3').data().kendoListView.dataSource.data()[0];
```

Or with jquery, you just use

```
$('#listView.product1 h3').text("Some updated text");
```

or

```
$('#listView div.product1 h3').text("Some updated text");
```

if you want it to search in divs only.

Comment: Its not working. i want to use .set method to set data in datasource. if we use .text then it set in dom but not in datasource so when we change page in kendo grid then change text not display.